What does 'scope' mean here?
What does 'scope' mean in this context?

Marx mentions the English Socialists with praise in "The Poverty of Philosophy" (1847). They, like him, tend to base their arguments upon a Ricardian theory of value, but they
have not his scope or erudition or scientific breadth.

Two possible meanings based on dictionary definitions: 1. ability and talent 2. the extent of subjects that Marx dealt with

In this context, scope means vision or range:
Cambridge Dictionary - Scope:
The range of a subject covered by a book, programme, discussion, class, etc.:

I'm afraid that problem is beyond/outside the scope of my lecture.
Oil painting does not come within the scope of a course of this kind.
We would now like to broaden/widen the scope of the enquiry and look
at more general matters.

